# Dependency from github is not resolved on gradle, what to do in this case?

Tags: android, github, gradle

I'm trying to import a library from github on my project ( link: https://github.com/justasm/DragLinearLayout)

However, importing on this way:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.jmedeisis:draglinearlayout:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile files('libs/.jar')
}
```

on my gadle file doesn't work ( error: `Failed to resolve: com.jmedeisis:draglinearlayout:1.1.0` ).

What are my solutions in this case? Is there a clean way to fix it or to import a github project otherwhise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following EROR's answer, I've succeed with something a bit easier by adding

`allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}`

on my gradle file.

Answer (score 3):

Gradle downloads binary from maven central repo by default not from github. And this package is not in maven central repo.

You can do those:

1. This package is in jcenter repository. [Click to see the package](https://bintray.com/elemyntic/android/draglinearlayout/view)

Add the following repository in your gradle file

```
repositories {
maven {
    url  "http://dl.bintray.com/elemyntic/android" 
   }
}
```

2. Clone The github project. and build it using gradle build, install it. use mavenLocal() in your repository. And you can use this artifact.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but as an android beginner, may I ask you some things? What do you mean by install it and how to use mavenLocal()?

Comment: Install it - u can clone the git project and build it in your local machine. Though it is not the standered way. gradle build will build the project. Then it will make a binary in your local machine. And u can use it.

The standered system is to use the specified repository. Hope it will solve the problem.